# Extend global object using ES2015 module syntax

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, module

I have the following declaration for extending Jest with new matchers, which works but triggers the lint `@typescript-eslint/no-namespace`:

```js
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Matchers<R> {
      toHave: <K>(key: K) => R;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a new syntax that would be equivalent to this without triggering my lint?